I want to utilize SwiftUI to place a button in the status bar like a photo editor
How do I place a button in the status bar like in the Photos app? My guess is that Apple would have placed it without using the ignore safe area. I'm hoping for different solutions on how to place it.
I used the code below to accomplish something similar.

VStack {
  HStack {
    Button(action: addItem) {
      Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
    }.padding([.top, .leading], 25)
    Spacer()
                
  }.ignoresSafeArea()
  Node()
}

My code

"I dare say Apple would have placed it without using ignoresSafeArea." Well, okay. They might have even used private APIs. What kind of answer are you expecting?

I would like to get a solution on how I can place a button on a dynamic island or notch side like Apple's Photos app.

Also, the talk about ignore safe area is just an opinion.

Can you update your post with a screenshot of the Photos app showing the button you're describing? It would help avoid confusion, especially now that the Photos app has changed in iOS 18.

I just signed up and it won't let me post images, so I'll give you the image address
https://www.apple.com/newsroom/videos/videos-2024/autoplay/2024/ios-18-apple-intelligence-clean-up-tool/posters/Apple-WWDC24-iOS-18-Apple-Intelligence-Clean-Up-tool-240610.jpg.large_2x.jpg
My question is about the Cancel and Done buttons in the status bar of that image!

This is exactly the sort of thing you would want to ignore safe area for. The safe area is the area that cannot be blocked by things like the camera where they have no pixels to display the content. You want to go in that area on the left and right. That's a use case where you would want to use ignores safe area.
